# Is there a tool to automatically search un-used files in a web project?

Tags: website, project-management

Some files don't have any in-links,which is obsolete,

is there a tool to auto-detect such files?

Answer (score 0):

That is a very interesting question. What you could do is type your homepage URL into the spider tool [here](http://www.webconfs.com/search-engine-spider-simulator.php) and see if there are any pages on the server which do not show up on the list of "spidered links", but you will want to hand-check it before actually deleting anything.

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably better off at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).

It's been asked there a couple times at least. :)

https://serverfault.com/questions/107343/dead-page-checker

https://serverfault.com/questions/37750/is-there-an-easy-way-to-generate-a-report-on-dead-files-in-iis

Answer (score 0):

FrontPage used to have functionality for this (one of the very few things that made it worth using). Dunno if it still does though.